# Generate client for only one of the Service Contract interfaces available on a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service-reference, servicecontract

I am currently refactoring a large WCF service which consisted of one service contract interface ("SCI" from here on) used by multiple different client applications. I have split up the SCI so that for each type of client application there is an SCI specific to the operations it requires. Some shared sections of the SCI's are defined in a base SCI, which the client application specific SCI's inherit.

There is a single service class that implements all the client specific SCI's. The fact that there is a diamond interface inheritance situation from the shared base SCI means, sometimes, that the same operation is available through multiple SCI's. When auto-generating clients (especially with async client methods), the resultant code has many ugly `<generated-type>1,2,3` etc...

In order to avoid this, I would like to add a service reference to each of the client applications that only generates a client for the SCI relevant to that particular application. This should result in no problems due to the same function appearing on different SCI's.

Is this possible?

Any other tips on achieving both modularity and code-reuse in this situation would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to create a service contract interface (you can manually do this, pull it from the original service implementation or auto generate it then copy it out).

Then instead of using a service reference use the channel factory to bind to your service (as below). This is a way nicer way of referencing WCF services.

You need the following refs to do this:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
```

Then you can use the following:

```
     var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
     var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://url:port"));
     factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

     var myService = factory.CreateChannel();

     myService.ServiceMethod();
```

Comment: So this would mean getting implementing a client using a Channel to the service? Is it possible to get auto generated client types, with the auto generated async operations?

Comment: Yeah you can do this by decorating you WCF service with ASYNC versions, see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132.aspx

IE:    
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginDivide(double n1, double n2, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    double EndDivide(IAsyncResult ar);
gives an async method

Comment: I see how to manually make the operations async, but doing this for dozens of operations when the code generator can do it for you seems ugly. I'd still like to know about getting the code generation for specific service contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Luke's suggestion worth to try. The 'ChannelFactory' way has many advantages then the  auto-generating way: you can keep the comments of your SCi, and no need to update reference after SCI changes.

In production, you may need to do some Singleton chache for performance, and separate SCI for Service implementation, so you can reference your SCI both in client and  Service implementation.

You have mentioned 'async', I think this may be a Binding or Behavior configuration issuse.

```
private ChannelFactory CreateFactoryInstance<T>(string endpointConfigurationName, string endpointAddress)
{
    ChannelFactory factory = null;
    factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(endpointConfigurationName, new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
    factory.Open();
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Guess I'll give channel factory approach a try when I'm back at work tomorrow, as you're both recommending it.